# How do I wrap a column HEADER in SharePoint Online Modern List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, modern-pages

[image: Column Headers]
How do I wrap a column HEADER in SharePoint Online Modern List? Seems there are only JSON solutions for the column's text, but not for the actual headers as shown on the picture with red circles.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question, the New Experience doesn't support any custom coding to wrap your column Header.

Here is a similar case for your reference:

- [Can we word wrap the column titles inside list view](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/269381/can-we-word-wrap-the-column-titles-inside-list-vie.html)